# How many years had Moses already been married to Tsipora in Paran desert?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu

How many years had **Moses** already been married to Tsipora in the Paran desert, when Moses divorced her *(according to Rashi in Numbers 12;1)*?

Comment: I think there is a Midrash that mentions Moses timeline 40 years in Egypt growing up another 40 in Midyan and another 40 years in the desert. If that’s what you’re referring to.

Comment: @DanielRoss How could it be, if it's written (Ex 7;6) that he was 80 years old when he came in front of Pharaoh?

Comment: I think it would be 3 years. Because he was 80+ at Sinai, this link quotes a Midrash that he was 77 when he married Tzipora: https://www.ohr.edu/7253